# Pycharm remote debugging No such file or directory error

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to use debug a python file on remote linux server by following instructions in https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/.

Even though I followed all the instructions, when debugging or executing remote file on local computer, it raises [Errno2] No such file or directory

```
ssh://user@0.0.0.0:22/home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/bin/python3.6 -u /home/user/dir1/group/algorithm/da_rnn_test.py
bash: line 0: cd: /home/user/dir1/group/algorithm: No such file or directory
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/bin/python3.6: can't open file '/home/user/dir1/group/algorithm/da_rnn_test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Strange thing is that I've never set path mapping nor deployment configurations to such `cd: /home/user/dir1/group/algorithm: No such file or directory`.

Here are my configurations for Project Deployment and Interpreter Path mappings:

- Project Interpreter: `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/bin/python3.6`
- Path mappings: `<Project root>→/home/user/desktop/WorkSpace/dir1/github/dir1`
- Deployment

  - Connection > Root path: `/home/user/desktop/WorkSpace/dir1/github/dir1`
  - Mappings

    - Local Path: `C:\Users\qraft\PycharmProjects\DA_RNN_dev`
    - Deployment path on server 'linux server': `/`
    - Web path on server 'linux server': `/`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @diraria this is old post.. and I don't remember if I found the solution. However, I just gave up using pycharm remote debugger and instead using ipdb with ssh terminal.